# CSS themes in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, themes, angular-cli

What will be the best way to implement plugin-able CSS themes for an Angular 2 app?
And what will be the recommended file structure? Currently I'm using the one generated by angular-cli.

Comment: File structure provided by angular-cli is going to be your best bet. That's the tool people will use to build production ready angular2 applications most of the time.

Comment: I agree and that's why I use it. But what about CSS themes?

Answer (score 0):

We have several ways to add styles to a component:

- inline in the template HTML
- by setting styles or styleUrls metadata
- with CSS imports

Inline styles:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'test.html',
  styles: [`
    .card {
      height: 20px;
      width: 80px;
    }
  `],
})
```

Use external styles sheets:

```
@Component({
  styleUrls: ['css/mystyle.css'],
  templateUrl: 'test.html',
})
```

CSS imports:

```
@import 'hero-details-box.css';
```

Component styles also have special selectors from the world of shadow DOM style scoping. e.g. there may be a CSS theme class applied to the document:

```
:host-context(.theme-light) h2 {
  background-color: #eef;
}
```

As a common practice split a component's code, HTML, and CSS into three separate files in the same directory:

```
quest-summary.component.ts
quest-summary.component.html
quest-summary.component.css
```

Please visit [Component styles](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html) to learn more.

If you want to further enhance it and use SAS visit [ANGULAR2 SASS](http://www.angulartypescript.com/angular-2-sass/) for more details.

```
styleUrls: ['./sassexample.component.scss']
```

If you want to use a libraries for UI comnponents please checkout following:

[PrimeNG](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/)

[Material](https://material.angular.io/)

[NG bootsrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)

Hoping this helps.

Cheers !!

Comment: I know that and that's not what I asked. I asked about CSS themes. How would you plugin an external CSS theme in the example above?

Comment: My question is not about UI component libraries. Let's suppose that I want to create my own components and add themes.

Comment: If you want to create your own component and add themes, then you can write your own css file and use appropriate theme, added a snippet in answer to show how to use theme, also added a link to learn more about component styles.

Comment: I know how to do it, but what's the best way to organize?

Comment: @AdrianBer - Have added some more details, will keep adding as we continue to learn angular 2.

Comment: None of these actually respond to the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Angular cli has built in support for css preprocessors such as sass and less, which are great for css themes. This issue is better solved if you focus on how to make themes through less/sass then how to do it in angular

I would recommend on your root element having the following for your root component:

**app.component.html**

```
<div [ngClass]="theme">
   <div class="widget">TEST</div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // this allows parent styles to influence children
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public theme: string;

    constructor() {}

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.theme = ... some logic to set theme here ...
    }
}
```

**app.component.scss**

```
.theme1 {
     .widget {
        background-color: red;
     }
}

.theme2 {
     .widget {
        background-color: blue;
     }
}
```

[This is just a simple example, A quick google reveals many in depth guides on how do to theming in sass](https://www.google.com/search?q=sass%20site%20theme)

Comment: I know how to do theming in Sass. My question was if there's a standard way to organize themes/theme files in Angular 2. I suspect there isn't. Your idea is pretty good, but what if I don't want to load all the themes in CSS?